# index multiple modals on 1 page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code
a picture gallery when clicking on a picture , it opens a modal
now I want a different modal for each picture . can I index the modals  ?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column1">
        <img src="images/thumbs/img01.JPG" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class ="hover-shadow">
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
        <img src="images/thumbs/img02.JPG" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow">
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
        <img src="images/thumbs/img03.JPG"  onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow">
    </div>
    <div class="column1">
        <img src="images/thumbs/img04.JPG" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_lightbox

Comment: Monasha , this is the example, but It shows the same lightbox  whenever you click on a picture. I want a different licghtbox according to the different pictures